# Adding to Devise's Registrations Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have a `user` model via devise and a `collective` model. I'm trying to create an invite system such that a user can invite a person to the website via email. When this person joins the website, a `user` is created and this new user will automatically be added to a collective using a token (the collective they are added to is chosen by the inviting user). I have the invite system working up to the point that a non-user receives an email with a sign up link (with a token in the url) and gets to the sign up page. I cannot however manage to get this person added to a `collective` once they submit the registration form.

I am currently getting the error `Validation failed: Owner can't be blank` due to the line `resource.collectives.push(org)`in the `create` action. Help would be much appreciated!

**My Custom Registrations Controller (I copied & slightly modified the Devise Registration Controller code)**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
    @token = params[:invite_token]
    build_resource({})
    @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
    if @validatable
      @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
    end
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with self.resource

end

def create

build_resource(sign_up_params)
    #added @token
    @token = params[:invite_token]

    resource_saved = resource.save

    #added if @token logic
    if @token != nil
       org =  Invite.find_by_token(@token).collective
       resource.collectives.push(org)
    end

    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end

end
```

Comment: Hold on... you've extended Devise's class. Are you sure you need **all** this code if you only modified it **a bit**? None of it can be replaced with `super`? `new` seems like a good candidate for that.

Comment: I'm actually not positive I do. I just thought that if I inserted `@token` logic into the middle of the `create` action, I couldn't use `super` (given that there is a redirect at the end of the `create` action)

Comment: You're absolutely right about `new` though. I can `super` that

Comment: What is `owner` and why is it validated?

Comment: I don't think Owner is anything. I think it is saying it doesn't understand what `resource.collectives` means. A collective belongs_to a user and thus I am trying to add the new user to a collective (org) via resource which devise defines as `instance_variable_get(:"@#{resource_name}")`.

Comment: If `collectives` are defined on `User` (`has_many`?), then it should know. Otherwise it would have raised a `NameError`. Let's try tracing from the error message instead of guesswork. So?

Comment: Owner doesn't mean anything in devise or my app. I thought it was saying that it doesn't understand the Owner 'resource'

Comment: Weird. `Owner` is nothing, but validation fails... try tossing in `pry-byebug` gem and do a `binding.pry` inside `create`. Have a look at the vid [here](http://pryrepl.org/) for an example course of action. Examine the situation. Right now, I don't get it.